# Should i rebuild a dependent lib after system update?

Tags: linux, distribution, libs

I have some fear when i update my system libraries. For example, i made `make && make install` for a custom lib (i.e. `libhell`, there is no this library in repo) that depends on libssl-dev>0.5. Then apt offers me to update `libssl-dev`. Should i rebuild `libhell` against new `libssl-dev`?

Always it worked fine after updates and without rebuilds, but what about binary safety? All the time i build own packages on bin-dist systems i feel i'm doing something wrong...

Comment: What is your `libhell`? Any URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why package systems exist.

If your `libhell` binary library is dynamic library (that is a `libhell.so` shared object, with position independent code) and if the dependency `libssl-dev` didn't change its API (e.g. if its version number didn't change), then you don't need to recompile and reinstall your `libhell`.

If you feel that your `libhell` depends upon a changed feature (or data) of `libssl-dev` then you should recompile it.

Better recompile your `libhell` more often than needed.

See also the [Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Comment: So, if i can't say (in real i never can say it), that there's no changes of the API's behavior in a target library (`libhell` was a subst for asterisk+dahdi_tools+libpri+span_dsp and so on), it will be better if i will rebuild all depended libs. Ok, now is the time to write a custom build script for this chain. Thanks.